# How to use two exec_command in a ssh connection in python paramiko lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I Want To using exec_command in a ssh connection.
my code:

```
from paramiko import *
Connection = SSHClient()
Connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())

# Try Connecting To Device.
try:
    Connection.connect("192.168.1.1",timeout=60)
except Exception as Error:
    return str(Error)


STDIn,STDOut,Error = Connection.exec_command("sh ver")
Result = STDOut.read()
print(Result)

STDIn,STDOut,Error = Connection.exec_command("sh ver")
Result = STDOut.read()
print(Result)
```

first exec_command is working.
but i get this error in second exec_command:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: SSH session not active
```

Comment: What kind of device are you connecting to? Is it a general-purpose computer such as a linux system? Or is it something specialized like a router?

Answer (score -2):

can't tell you for sure why paramiko close the ssh session in your case.

you can try using context manager `with`, in this case you don't need a timeout, python will close the connection after executing commands

```
import paramiko


try:
    with paramiko.SSHClient() as Connection:
        Connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        Connection.connect(host="192.168.1.1") # username/password ???
        _, STDOut, _ = Connection.exec_command("sh ver")
        Result = STDOut.read()
        print(Result)
        _,STDOut, _ = Connection.exec_command("sh ver")
        Result = STDOut.read()
        print(Result)

except Exception as Error:
    return str(Error)
```